Can a time series with a seasonal component be stationary?
According to Rob Hyndman's Forecasting Principles and Practice, "time series with trends, or with seasonality, are not stationary — the trend and seasonality will affect the value of the time series at different times". This makes sense to me.
But I came across this blog post, that says the following:

Let:
X1t = Y1t + S1t
X2t = Y2t + S2t       ;     t = 1, 2, ........
where the two Y series have no seasonal component; and the two S
series are stochastic and strongly seasonal. The X series are
stationary.

What I don't understand is if the X series contain an additive seasonal component from the S series, wouldn't that make the X series seasonal and thus non-stationary contradicting Rob Hyndman?

Asked&answered before https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131092/does-a-seasonal-time-series-imply-a-stationary-or-a-non-stationary-time-series, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438303/can-a-time-series-be-stationary-and-still-have-seasonality, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491785/can-stationary-time-series-contain-regulary-cycles-and-periods-with-different-fl, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484983/stationary-process-with-seasonality-and-trend and more by searching ...

Fair enough. Based on that first link, sounds like there isn't a consensus as to whether it is stationary or not.

@LucaGuarro, see my newly posted answers here and here.
